# How to implement tages mechanism like stackoverflow tag

Tags: php, jquery-ui

How to implement tages mechanism  like stackoverflow tag?

Using PHP, MySQL and JS.JQUERY

Comment: what you have tried so far? Please provide your code...

Answer (score 1):

Wendy, there is a Jquery UI plugin (**tag it**) on github,
Provides same functionalities like `SO autocomplete tags`

here is the link to download : https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

and here is home page link : http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/

and small demo code you can use as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myTags").tagit();
    });
</script>

<ul id="myTags">
    <!-- Existing list items will be pre-added to the tags -->
    <li>javascript</li>
    <li>python</li>
    <li>haskell</li>
</ul>
```

see the screenshot below

[image]

let me know if any help needed.